# Is it possible to use some form of code for example in PUTTY to execute a task which is done Remote desktop connection?

Tags: automation, remote-access

Basically, 
Every morning at 6:00AM I have to do login to remote desktop, open a program, and click on a few things to make reservations before anyone else does.

I want to know if there is any other way that this can be done by simply turning it into some form of a code and executing it instead of manually doing it. Of course, time is precious here and the task needs to be done at the same pace if not faster.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you're getting at, but if you have a Windows machine at hand you can do this easily with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com). It comes with a tool called AutoScriptWriter, so you can record your actions and have the program write the script for you -- perfect for scheduling scripts to run with Task Scheduler and automating things like this.

**Note:** ensure your solution works properly before scheduling it to avoid potential problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a macro recorder that can create a batch file or executable that can be scheduled would work.